# Play Framework Forwarding Body Parser fails randomly after upgrading Play framework from 2.6.11 to 2.8.19

Tags: java, playframework

We are using a slightly updated [ForwardingBodyParser](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaBodyParsers#Directing-the-body-elsewhere) that does some additional request header manipulations, but is identical to the example otherwise.

The problem is that after upgrading from java play 2.6.11 to 2.8.19 we start to experience the following errors randomly (pretty seldom and mostly right after the application startup):

```
[[31merror[0m] http.Errors - Internal server error
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false) only supports one subscriber (which is allowed, see reactive-streams specification, rule 1.11)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:26)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:484)
    at scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$parasitic$.execute(ExecutionContext.scala:222)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:429)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false) only supports one subscriber (which is allowed, see reactive-streams specification, rule 1.11)
    at akka.stream.impl.ReactiveStreamsCompliance$.rejectAdditionalSubscriber(ReactiveStreamsCompliance.scala:62)
    at akka.stream.impl.VirtualPublisher.rec$6(StreamLayout.scala:481)
    at akka.stream.impl.VirtualPublisher.subscribe(StreamLayout.scala:486)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.body.NettyReactiveStreamsBody.write(NettyReactiveStreamsBody.java:60)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.writeRequest(NettyRequestSender.java:426)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.writeRequest(NettyConnectListener.java:80)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.access$100(NettyConnectListener.java:37)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onSuccess(NettyConnectListener.java:139)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onSuccess(NettyConnectListener.java:129)
    at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:24)
```

It seems like sometimes application subscribes twice to the `Source` in the `Accumulator`. I can reproduce the same issue 100% of times if I do it explicitly, but I'd love to know how it could be happening in the Play internals and how it could be resolved

Comment: Any chance you're using `InputStream` somewhere? We've had same errors when using them with Akka stream, removing these usages removed the errors.

Comment: no, the code we are using is almost identical to what is provided for the ForwardingBodyParser in the Play user guide. We are just altering a couple of headers. That's it